# How can I change a grandchild widget's attribute?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

```
class Window(ctk.CTk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    self.resizable(False, False)
    self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    LoginFrame = LoginFrame(self)

  def check_login(self,u,p):
    if u == "user" and p == "bhjs":
      #change the text of lbl_message
    elif u == "admin" and p == "pass":
      #change the text of lbl_message
    else:
      #change the text of lbl_message

class LoginFrame(ctk.CTkFrame):
  def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__(master)

    self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

    lbl_welcome = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Welcome. Please Login.")
    lbl_welcome.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2,pady=10)
    lbl_username = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="username:")
    lbl_username.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky="E")
    lbl_password = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="password:")
    lbl_password.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky="E")
    ent_username = ctk.CTkEntry(self,placeholder_text="username", placeholder_text_color="gray")
    ent_username.grid(column=1,row=1,padx=12,pady=10,sticky="W")
    ent_password = ctk.CTkEntry(self,placeholder_text="password", placeholder_text_color="gray",show="*")
    ent_password.grid(column=1,row=2,padx=12,pady=10,sticky="W")
    btn_login = ctk.CTkButton(self,text="login",cursor="hand2",command=lambda: master.check_login(ent_username.get(),ent_password.get()))
    btn_login.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=2,pady=10)
    lbl_message = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="")
    lbl_message.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=2,pady=10)
```

here is my attempt of a login system using customTkinter. I am trying to make a login message that either shows "login as user", "login as admin", and "login failed" by changing the text the lbl_message.

When I try to access the label object by `LoginFrame.lbl_message.config(text="text")`, An exception is thrown saying LoginFrame do not have the lbl_message attribute. How can I access the lbl_message label here?

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are just local variables. They need to be made into instance variables, and you need a reference to the instance.

To do that, you first need to rename the `LoginFrame` variable so that it doesn't clash with the class. Second, you need to make it an attribute of the object (eg: `self.loginFrame`).

Similarly, you need to rename `lbl_message` to make it an attribute of the object (eg: `self.lbl_message`).

Once you do that, you should be able to use `self.loginFrame.lbl_message`.

Comment: Just changed lbl_message to self.lbl_message when initializing and it worked. Thank you.